# Crash when starting new Activity

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio

Hello i'm trying to make an application that can log into a website [Corobizar.com](http://corobizar.com) in Main Activity and see a stream in Second Activity for the stream i know how to do but when i try to start Second Activity my applications crash
Here's the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="arceos.com.corobizartv">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/logomini"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".SecondActivity"/>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

and here's the code of mainActivity :

```
package arceos.com.corobizartv;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String url = "corobizar.com";
Button login;
EditText UserNom;
EditText PassMot;
String Username = "";
String Password = "";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            UserNom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NomUser);
            Username = UserNom.getText().toString();
            PassMot = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PassMot);
            Password = PassMot.getText().toString();
            new Title().execute();
        }
    });
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String value = intent.getStringExtra("key"); //if it's a string you stored.

}

public class Title extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .data("username", Username, "password", Password)
                    .timeout(60000)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla")
                    .post();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

}
```

Here's the layout mainActivity:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="69dp"
        android:id="@+id/NomUser"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/PassMot"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
        android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:hint="Password"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="248dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Connecte-toi"
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

</FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the logcat :

> 05-30 22:05:33.714 21863-21863/arceos.com.corobizartv
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                           Process: arceos.com.corobizartv, PID: 21863
>                                                                           android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class
>   {arceos.com.corobizartv/arceos.com.corobizartv.SecondActivity}; have
>   you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1761)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1485)
>                                                                               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3821)
>                                                                               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3782)
>                                                                               at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:843)
>                                                                               at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4092)
>                                                                               at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4060)
>                                                                               at
>   arceos.com.corobizartv.MainActivity$Title.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:80)
>                                                                               at
>   arceos.com.corobizartv.MainActivity$Title.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:62)
>                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
>                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
>                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.
>
> handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 05-30
>   22:05:35.671 21863-21863/arceos.com.corobizartv I/Process: Sending
>   signal. PID: 21863 SIG: 9

Bye

Comment: What are you trying to do with `String value = intent.getStringExtra("key"); `? How did you start this activity? I am suspecting a `NullPointerException` - so please show us the error in your log.

Comment: Show log, please :)

Comment: Do you have a **@string/app_name** defined?

Comment: I'm trying to launch the second activity with login cookies

Answer (score 1):

`<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".SecondActivity"/>` is defined inside an `<activity>` tag. Must be declared outside:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="arceos.com.corobizartv">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/logomini"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".SecondActivity"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Correct. Small advise use the full name of the class in the Manifest file "arceos.com.corobizartv.SecondActivity"